# Another exception was thrown: dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _PagesTestWidgetState.initState() completed

Tags: flutter, dart

How Can i fix this here is my code the error is on initState and didUpdateWidget i want some one to help me on this when i taped on the menu on the drawer i can not go to the page that i want to navigate to and her's my code i am using route to navigate between pages so i want you to help me please to solve this error thanks all

> ```
> class _PagesTestWidgetState extends State<PagesTestWidget> {
>   initState() {
>      _selectTab(widget.currentTab);
>      super.initState();
>   }
>
>     @override
>    void didUpdateWidget(PagesTestWidget oldWidget) {
>     _selectTab(oldWidget.currentTab);
>      super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
>    }
>     void _selectTab(int tabItem) {
> setState(() {
>   widget.currentTab = tabItem;
>   switch (tabItem) {
>     case 0:
>       widget.currentTitle = S.of(context).notifications;
>       widget.currentPage = NotificationsWidget();
>       break;
>     case 1:
>       widget.currentTitle = S.of(context).profile;
>       widget.currentPage = ProfileWidget();
>       break;
>     case 2:
>       widget.currentTitle = settingsRepo.setting?.appName;
>       widget.currentPage = HomeWidget();
>       break;
>     case 3:
>       widget.currentTitle = S.of(context).my_orders;
>       widget.currentPage = OrdersWidget();
>       break;
>     case 4:
>       widget.currentTitle = S.of(context).favorites;
>       widget.currentPage = FavoritesWidget();
>       break;
>   }
> });
>  }
>
>    @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>      return WillPopScope(
>       onWillPop: () async => false,
>       child: Scaffold(
>         drawer: DrawerWidget(),
>         appBar: AppBar(
>           backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
>         elevation: 0,
>         centerTitle: true,
>       title: Text(
>         widget.currentTitle ??
>             settingsRepo.setting?.appName ??
>             S.of(context).home,
>         style: Theme.of(context)
>             .textTheme
>             .title
>             .merge(TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3)),
>       ),
>       actions: <Widget>[
>         new ShoppingCartButtonWidget(
>             iconColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
>             labelColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
>       ],
>     ),
>     body: widget.currentPage,
>     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
>       type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
>       selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
>       selectedFontSize: 0,
>       unselectedFontSize: 0,
>       iconSize: 22,
>       elevation: 0,
>       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
>       selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 28),
>       unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(1),
>       currentIndex: widget.currentTab,
>       onTap: (int i) {
>         this._selectTab(i);
>       },
>       items: [
>         BottomNavigationBarItem(
>           icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
>           title: new Container(height: 0.0),
>         ),
>         BottomNavigationBarItem(
>           icon: Icon(Icons.person),
>           title: new Container(height: 0.0),
>         ),
>         BottomNavigationBarItem(
>             title: new Container(height: 5.0),
>             icon: Container(
>               width: 42,
>               height: 42,
>               decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                 color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
>                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
>                   Radius.circular(50),
>                 ),
>                 boxShadow: [
>                   BoxShadow(
>                       color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.4),
>                       blurRadius: 40,
>                       offset: Offset(0, 15)),
>                   BoxShadow(
>                       color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.4),
>                       blurRadius: 13,
>                       offset: Offset(0, 3))
>                 ],
>               ),
>               child: new Icon(Icons.home,
>                   color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
>             )),
>         BottomNavigationBarItem(
>           icon: new Icon(Icons.fastfood),
>           title: new Container(height: 0.0),
>         ),
>         BottomNavigationBarItem(
>           icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
>           title: new Container(height: 0.0),
>         ),
>       ],
>     ),
>   ),
> );   
> } 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it Now Thanks all

```
 initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        _selectTab(widget.currentTab);
    });
  }
```